# Disable options menu where its not specified in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm an Android noob. I've written a main activity with an options menu. Each option opens an activity of its own. When I click the options menu in each of the sub-activities I get a "settings" menu. How can I remove or disable this, such that only the main activity has an options menu?

What I've tried: within each sub-activity, I've gotten an instance of the menu item and disabled it.

Code follows first for the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Show current settings");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 0, "Edit current settings");
    return true;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ShowSettingsActivity.class));
        return true;

    case 1:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

For minor activity

```
public class EditSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_settings);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_settings, menu);
    MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.menu.edit_settings);
    mi.setEnabled(false);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't it because you inflate a menu inside your minor activities?

Comment: @nicopico When I comment out the line starting with getMenuInflater, I get a NullPointerException

Comment: That would be because the menu has no `edit_settings` item, so `mi == null`. If you don't want an option menu in your activity, just don't override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` from the activities (`ShowSettingsActivity` and 
`EditSettingsActivity`) in which you don't need the options menu.